# Python dates filling in blanks, pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a dataframe with about two years worth of dates.   I am trying to create a new column that will indicate if the date has earnings reported on that day.   How can I do this?

DF

```
 Date             Stock    
 2018-02-15       100
 .
 .
 .
 2018-04-02       122
 2018-04-03       119
 2018-04-04       120
```

My attempt I looked up the earning dates then I tired to join but failed.

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Earnings_Date", "Earnings Reported"],
              data=[['05/01/2018','Yes'],['02/15/2018','Yes'],['10/31/2017','Yes'],['08/01/2017','Yes']])
```

Ideally, I would like my DF to look like

DF

```
 Date             Stock       Earnings Reported
 2018-02-15       100         Yes
 .
 .
 .
 2018-04-02       122         No
 2018-04-03       119         No
 2018-04-04       120         No
```

Comment: What is the condition for filling with Yes or No?

Comment: Based on the dates in "my attempt"   I gave the dates there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for join, merging.  Just check to see if Date is in the Earnings_Date column.

```
df['Earnings Report'] = np.where(df['Date'].isin(mydf['Earnings_Date']),'Yes','No')
```

Where mydf is the Earnings Report dataframe, and df is the original stock dataframe.

```
        Date  Stock Earnings Report
0 2018-02-15    100             Yes
1 2018-04-02    122              No
2 2018-04-03    119              No
3 2018-04-04    120              No
```